# Advantages of RepositoryClassLoader of jboss over stand alone custom class loader

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, hotdeploy

in my application I am looking to develop Java custom class loader to enforce hot deployment of my java classes. I was thinking to go on by extending java.lang.ClassLoader. But  during a discussion over the design on my colleague suggested to use jboss custom class loaders (by repository class loaders). In both the cases,I have to write the  class loading  part. But what is the advantage of jboss class loaders over my own custom class loaders? I am not able to find it. Can someone help me to understand it ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at "out-of-the-box" solutions like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) with essentially do this. The license is likely cheaper than reimplementing it.